# How to list all CRM fields which are dirty in console?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, xrm

I have been looking for a way to get the list of all dirty fields in the CRM form to determine the what was changed and need to be saved in the browser console. This will help me debugging the javascript or other CRM related issues in general

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code for your reference

```
var attribs = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get();
```

to get the list of all fields in the from and then call the function `getIsDirty()` for it as

```
var filterDirty = attribs.filter(function(elem,index,attribs){   
        var name =  elem.getName();
        return (Xrm.Page.getAttribute(name).getIsDirty() === true);
});
```

Now the `filterDirty`  will hold an array of all the dirty fields and you can just print it with the map as

```
filterDirty.map(function(e){ console.log(e.getName()); });
```

**Note:** Just make sure Xrm is available you can see why there is additional bit of code before the what i described above from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43671799/3057246)

the whole code will look something like this for you

```
// get the correct frame
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) //loop through 0 to 4
    if(frames[i].Xrm.Page.ui != undefined) //check if undefined    
    {
        Xrm = frames[i].Xrm;  //assign Xrm
        console.info("~: Xrm updated with frame " + i + " :~"); //show info
        break; //breakout the loop
    }

//Query
var attribs = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get();

//Filter
var filterDirty = attribs.filter(function(elem,index,attribs){   
        var name =  elem.getName();
        return (Xrm.Page.getAttribute(name).getIsDirty() === true);
});

//print
filterDirty.map(function(e){
  console.log(e.getName()); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the developer tools (F12), select the Console and enter the following:

```
Xrm.Page.data = Xrm.Page.data || frames[0].Xrm.Page.data || frames[1].Xrm.Page.data; Xrm.Page.data.entity.getDataXml()
```

The returned Xml will list the dirty fields and their values as XML. For example

```
<contact><firstname>changed on form but not saved in db</firstname></contact>
```